# iphone app based on flash air supports in-app purchase, google admob, iad?

Tags: flash, air, in-app-purchase, push-notification, admob

I have few questions related to apps developed based on flash air for ios.
1. How to add in-app purchase?
2. How to add google admob, or iAd, or any other types of advertisement in my app?
3. How to send SMS or make a phone call?
4. How to add Push notification?

I know how to do these with a native app, but totally clueless when it comes to flash. Please help...Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please see the second answer on [Possible to do In-App Purchasing using Adobe Air SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914011/possible-to-do-in-app-purchasing-using-adobe-air-sdk) which might help.

In short. With AIR 3 It is now possible to achieve all the functionalists you noted above.

For how To see: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/extending-air.html

For readymade sample for In-App Purchases through AIR on iOS see: http://code.google.com/p/in-app-purchase-air-ios/

Answer (score 1):

There is a flash animation library for developer to add admob advertising into Adobe AIR 3 mobile application.
It is easy and free to use. AIR 3.4 includes notifications and also send sms ref to `flash.net.navigateToURL`.
http://lilili87222.github.com/admob-for-flash/