# Possible to do In-App Purchasing using Adobe Air SDK

Tags: ios, air, in-app-purchase

I'm working on a digital series of interactive books for a client using the Adobe Air SDK.  Recently the client decided they want the ability to add in-app purchasing to build a little library of books you've already purchased and books you've yet to.  I'm aware these features exist natively and through others like phone gap and titanium but the books are already created and the timeframe won't allow these options.

Is it possible or does anyone know how to hook into the in-app purchasing feature of iOS via Airs mobile SDK?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the new AIR 3.0 SDK (Available on Labs and will be releasing soon) from http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/air3.html which has a new feature called Native Extensions. Which allows you to jump to/from AS into obj-c/c code. Using this you can implement the storekit functionality in an onj-c static library and call this functionality from Actionscript.

I have written one sample for in-app purchases at http://code.google.com/p/in-app-purchase-air-ios/

The homepage includes links to ADC articles which explain how you can implement,use,package the native extensions.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: actually, this is a rather useful post, which links to a sample of the exact functionality requested.

Comment: would like to note that samumitra has not updated his native extension since dec 11, and currently there is a bug that does not return a list of already made purchases  (see http://code.google.com/p/in-app-purchase-air-ios/issues/detail?id=7)

Comment: Hi K2XL: As you can read on the mentioned issue page. Its an intermittent issue in StoreKit Native APIs. And all of the developers could not reproduce this after device reset. If you think this issue is valid and reproducible at your end please share the working binary with me. Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726654/skpayementqueue-restoring-transactions-finishes-without-calling-updatedtransac its a native iOS StoreKit issue that people face in Native Apps as well, and is beyond the scope of being fixed in ANE.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it may be possible with the latest release of AIR 3. Adobe has developed a feature called Native Extensions that will allow developers to write code in the target platforms native language and interface it with the ActionScript.

With this in mind, it sounds like a clever developer could write a framework for using the Native Extension feature to communicate with the in-app purchase API.

Let me know if someone does that :)